# Export Data into excel using SSIS 2008 with 5000 length column

Tags: excel, ssis, export

I need to create a SSIS package in 2008 which will export a query result into excel sheet. Comment column has length 5000 and whenever I try to export the data I am getting following error message:

"Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The output column Comments (255) has a length that is not valid. the length must be between 0 to 4000."

I need to apply some formating on the excel sheet like word wrap is it possible thourgh SSIS package. Any help would be highly appricaited. 
Thanks, Yogi

Answer (score 0):

Put a data conversion component in between your source and destination. You should be able to stipulate the data size.

Comment: I already put a data conversion component in between Souce and Destination and for the Commnet column data type "Unicode String[DT_WSTR] is being used however this data type support only 4000 chars and the length for Comment column is 5000.

Comment: any solution on this? im facing the same issue